# Role of SQLite in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone

What is the role of SQLLite in iPhone programming? Where do we use it? Is there any nice link to read around this topic in detail with sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a lightweight in-memory relational database, that can be used directly by iOS apps, or as a persistent store for [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html).

Here's a good list of resources about directly using [SQLite on iPhone](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/). And the Apple Developer Center has a lot of info on how to use it as a store for Core Data (and how to use Core Data itself, of course).